# LabVIEW: Removing all numbers in a string

Tags: string, labview

I would like to remove all numbers in a string.

For example,

[image]

I would like to convert String into String2.

Can anyone give me a small code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far? Below are 3 methods how to achieve it (could be even more ways of solution).

**UPD**: updated based on comment from [sweber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099181/sweber).

[image: VI Snippet]

Comment: Even simpler: The search&replace VI can be switched to use regular expressions. This and `replace all?=True` make it just one VI to call.