# To create a VI which removes all numbers from a string and counts them in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I need to create a VI which removes all numbers from a string and counts them in LabVIEW.

For example, if there's a string "12Anna33" this VI has to transform it into "Anna" and to count the amount of numbers in the string - 4.

How can I do this in LabVIEW?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LabVIEW: Removing all numbers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213172/labview-removing-all-numbers-in-a-string)

Comment: There was a similar question a few days back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213172/labview-removing-all-numbers-in-a-string 
The search&replace VI also returns the number of replacements, so not much more to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fixed solution from @Vignesh, which takes into account zeroes + uses conditional terminal for For Loop output:

[image: Fixed solution]

But, @sweber referred to even easier solution from another thread:

[image: Easier solution]

Answer (score -1):

As both previous answers given in the comment doesn't have count feature,  this will suit your requirement perfectly.

[image: Sample Vi Snip]

Drag and drop this Vi Snip to LabVIEW 2017 or Above

Comment: No he needs the no of numbers in the string not the sum of numbers

Comment: 'His' name is Anna, and on 'his' picture, 'he' looks quite female...
And  the question clearly states by giving an example that the input is "12Anna33" and the desired output is  "Anna" and the count of numbers, which is 4.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with "he", my fault - I've removed my comment. But, @Vignesh, your answer is not correct - if there are zeroes in the text, they are not counted (try to test with text like 01Anna02, it will give 2 as the output). I'll post fixed solution.